# Menu slide up leaving a gap in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[image: After sliding up, there is a gap underneath]

```
The code is here. Chrome and Firefox work well: http://jsfiddle.net/cAU9T/4/
```

It only happens in IE. But all versions of IE...
Any idea?

Comment: Not without your code...

Comment: What gap are you referring to?  The shadow line under the "Soccer" tab?

Comment: @DrydenLong http://jsfiddle.net/cAU9T/4/

Comment: @cale_b its not a shadow line but a white line if you compare soccer to others

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an IE glitch on rendering shadows. As a work around you could have an element below your shadowed element, to force the shadow area to be redrawn as suggested on this answer: [IE 9 and 10 box-shadow on resizing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703099/ie-9-and-10-box-shadow-on-resizing-element)

Your UL is absolute positioned, so nothing gets pushed when its height change. You can fix the problem just by adding a pseudo element to the UL itself:

```
ul.division:after { content: " "; display:block; height:15px; width:100%;}
```

Updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cAU9T/5/